# Anyone know of a tree table implementation for GWT using CellTable?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to be able to expand a row by adding more rows underneath it and expanding the page size so they fit. Not too complicated but I have had hassles trying to insert rows and so on with CellTable before so am hoping someone has solved this.

Comment: Use `FlexTable` instead. I think it is more suitable since it is built for expanding.

Comment: I am already using CellTable and need the speed it provides

Comment: @David Tinker can you maybe post the code see how uses the `CellTable` to add new rows?

Comment: @starcom Its a lot of ungodly hackery that I don't want to inflict on anyone else. I am planning to clean it up (basically treat the CellTable as a dumb view always showing all of a page that I control + ignore range change events + hook pager up to my 'driver' class instead) and will post it then.

Comment: I also have a hacked up CellTable implementation... ever find a solution for this question?

Comment: I did improve my hack. I have a class implementing HasRows that manages a HasData (e.g. CellTable) and is used as the display for the pager. The table always shows a page starting at 0 so I can vary the page size as rows are added etc without causing any problems. Nothing listens to range change events from the table. Its all driven by my class.

Answer (score 1):

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree

Comment: That one doesn't have columns like a table, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

All I could find is this [TreeTable component](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/TreeTable). Is not maintained, and it was for GWT 2.1.